# Cant Fetch/Change Store Value -REDUX (React Native )

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Im new to redux

I am simply want to show value in multiple screens . I need to update and display  store value after OnPress.

My Store

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

// const rootReducer = () => {

// }


import rootReducer from "../reducers/index.js";


export default store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

My Balance Reducer

```
const BalanceReducer = (state = '0', action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_BAL':
            return state
        default:
            return state

    }

}

export default BalanceReducer;
```

My Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class StartPage extends Component {



    _UpdateBal = () => {
        const text = 30;
        this.props.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_BAL', text });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Text style={styles.welcome}>Current Balance : {this.props.balance} </Text>

                <Button title={'Update Balance'} onPress={this._UpdateBal} />
                <Button title={'Login ->'} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('login')} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});

export default connect()(StartPage);
```

Let me know where i'm doing wrong. I cant get value on this.props.balance and dispatch action seems to be not updating too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see inside your rootReducer so I am assuming you are registering your Balance reducer correctly. But in your Balance reducer, your `UPDATE_BAL` action doesn't actually do anything - it just returns the state which is `'0'`. Please note how that is a **string with the value "0", not a number with the value 0**. In your component you want to set the balance as a number. To fix that, you can do this:

```
const BalanceReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_BAL':
            return state + action.text //add the action's value (which you send over from your component) to the stored value
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default BalanceReducer;
```

Besides that, you are missing a `mapStateToProps` which actually maps your app's state to your `StartPage` component's props:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        balance: state.BalanceReducer //now you can acccess the balance through this.props.balance
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(StartPage);
```